# derivative of function of T

Tags: derivatives

How do I take the derivative of:

$\left ( \frac{1}{T^4} \right ) \left (\frac{1}{K-T} \right )$

Can I just use the product rule? IT seems like it get pretty complicated pretty fast

Comment: The product rule should work. Do you know how to differentiate each term in the product separately? If you can do those, and you apply the product rule, it should give you the answer.

Comment: Applying the product rule would be just fine.

Comment: Yes you can use the product rule.

Comment: It seems to get pretty complicated...are there tricks to reduce it?

Comment: If you use quotient rule of differentiation you have to do the same level of work.

Answer (score 0):

Using the product rule it has to be:
$$
-\frac{4}{(K-T)T^{5}} + \frac{1}{(K-T)^{2}T^{4}}
$$

Comment: I don't think there should be a four in the second term.

Comment: And even a negative sign.

Comment: What about differentiating K-T again.

Answer (score 0):

$d(fg)/dx= g*df/dx+f*dg/dx$

$f=1/T^4$  ,   $g=1/(k-T)$

$df/dT=-4/T^5$  ,  $dg/dT=1/(k-T)^2$

I am sure you can carry out from here.

Comment: I think it should be $dg/dt=-1/(k-T)^2$.

Comment: You have missed a     -1 @nullgeppetto

Comment: Where? I have made some edits so far, so it is possible I had some typo...

Comment: $dg/dT = d/dT (1/(K-T))   * d/dT (K-T)

Comment: From the above comment it is equal to $-1/(K-T)^2 * -1$

Comment: Ok then, my fault! I quit!